# Ошибка do not list domain domain.ru in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains

Tags: postfix

Здравствуйте!

Настраиваю postfix.
При попытке приема почты в логе ошибка

```
do not list domain domain.ru in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
```

Но при этом в `main.cf` `mydestination` закомментирован, а

```
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/usr/local/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
```

в котором прописан доступ к таблице mysql в которой прописан домен, однако ошибка все-равно возникает и входящих писем через `roundecube` не видно.
Как это можно исправить?

Comment: пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос вывод `/usr/sbin/postconf mydestination virtual_mailbox_domains`.

Comment: но если применить телепатическую магию, возможно, вы либо записали в конфигурацию `myhostname = domain.ru`, либо то, что присвоили этой переменной, включили в таблицу доменов (в mysql) .

Comment: myhostname я тоже уже закомментировал. Вывод postconf такой mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost                     
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/usr/local/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_domains_map
s.cf

Comment: продолжая рекурсию, посмотрите, что (с точки зрения postfix-а) хранится в `myhostname` и `mydomain`, а потом убедитесь, что (после подстановки переменных), ни `$myhostname`, ни `localhost.$mydomain`, ни `localhost` не фигурируют в таблице с доменами используемой базы данных.

Comment: Очень странные результаты postconf myhostname mydomain выдал myhostname = subdomain.domain.ru (это правильный hostname сервера)
mydomain = domain.ru (который вообще нигде должен быть прописан) причем оба эти параметра в main.cf закомментированы. А в таблице domain в mysql да стоит subdomain.domain.ru

Comment: А в таблице domain в mysql, да стоит subdomain.domain.ru в таком виде passat.lipetsk.ru хост-домен 4 / 0 1 / 0 virtual НЕТ 2015-06-30 10:24:39 ДА редактировать удалить (скопировано из postfixadmin) Но если его оттуда удалить тогда вообще официально ни одного домена не останется.

Comment: 1. не описаны в конфигурации — запрашиваются у системы (postfix-у ведь надо знать эти значения). см. вывод `hostname` и `hostname --fqdn`. 2. вставляйте строки в вопрос, пожалуйста: в комментариях эта информация нечитабельна.

Comment: *ни одного домена не останется* — останется тот, что у `postfix`-а в переменной `mydomain` хранится. только он будет не виртуальный, а вполне себе реальный.

Comment: Так что же делать? Если postfix все равно возьмет их из системы, отключить virtual_mailbox_domains в конфиге?

Comment: я же не знаю, какие перед вами стоят задачи. если никаких доменов, кроме того, в который входит машина, не предвидится ни сейчас, ни в будущем, то отключайте.

Comment: У меня есть subdomain.domain.ru - который hostname для сервера, насколько я понял прописывать его отдельно в качестве виртуального домена не нужно. И есть domain2.ru на другом сервере, который я после завершения настройки хочу перенести на этот сервер, в том числе и ящики info@domain2.ru, postmaster@domain2.ru и т.д. Таким образом я удаляю из mysql-таблицы subdomain.domain.ru и прописываю там domian2.ru в качестве виртуального почтового домена, а когда поменяем записи в dns почта на ящики *@domain2.ru пойдет на мой сервер? Я правильно рассуждаю?

Comment: да, направление мысли — верное.

Comment: 1. я там выше неправильно написал: приниматься будет почта для всех доменов, перечисленных в `mydestination`. 2. после внесения другого домена в список виртуальных, почта для этого домена сразу же будет приниматься вашим сервером (если кто-то её вашему серверу вдруг отправит).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

скорее всего, в таблице с виртуальными доменами содержится реальный домен, к которому относится машина:

```
$ hostname --fqdn
```

в таком случае эту запись из таблицы следует убрать: для «родного» домена *postfix* (по умолчанию) и так будет принимать почту.

---

либо в той же таблице содержится одно из значений, которое содержится в переменной *postfix-а* `mydestination`. посмотреть текущее значение переменных можно командой:

```
$ /usr/sbin/postconf имя-переменной имя-ещё-одной-переменной ...
```

если переменная `mydestination` содержит, например, `$myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost`, то, запросив ещё значения переменных `myhostname` и `mydomain`, и подставив их вместо имён, следует проверить, не встречаются ли такие записи в таблице доменов, и удалить их оттуда.