# Как в roundcube читать почту системных пользователей?

Tags: postfix, roundcube

Здравствуйте!
Есть связка postfix, dovecot, postfixadmin, roundcube на freebsd
Подскажите пожалуйста, как в roundcube читать почту системных пользователей root, user и т.д.? Когда они у меня были прописаны в postfix в логе была ошибка 
*do not list domain domain.ru in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains*

Почту виртуальных ящиков читаю нормально.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**напоминание о [старом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/432811/178576)**: сообщение *do not list ...* было вызвано тем, что *domain.ru* **уже** присутствовал в списке *mydestinaion*.

---

если вам нужно, чтобы почта для *root@localhost* не считалась локальной (т.е. попадала не в файл `/var/spool/user` или в каталог `/home/user/.Mail` или как у вас сейчас настроено), а «складывалась» туда же, куда и другая почта для «виртуальных почтовых ящиков», то можно, к примеру, поступить так:

1. удалить *domain.ru* из списка *mydestination*
2. добавить *domain.ru* в список *virtual_mailbox_domains*
3. перезапустить *postfix*
4. переадресовать эту почту пользователю `root@domain.ru`, добавив в конец файла `/etc/aliases` строку такого вида:

   ```
   root: root@domain.ru
   ```
5. выполнить (от имени *root-а* или через *sudo*) команду `newaliases`
6. добавить пользователя *root@domain.ru* в *mysql*-таблицу пользователей (кажется, это можно сделать через интерфейс *roundcube*)

шаги с четвёртого по шестой можно повторить и для других локальных пользователей.